# sendGrid + firebase cloud functions: Email is not sending with Callable functions

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, google-cloud-functions, sendgrid

I'm new to javascript and I'm trying to send email with the firebase callable functions. the idea is to send code to user email from a cloud function when called from the iOS app. But the thing is, functions can be deployed but I'm not sure what is wrong with my code as it is not sending the email. I have already configure the Sendgrid api key and template id so it doesn't seems like the issue here. Plus the functions log on firebase is not returning any Error. Can someone help? here's my code

**Cloud Function code:**

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");
const SENDGRID_API_KEY = functions.config().sendgrid.key;
const TEMPLATE_ID = functions.config().sendgrid.template;
sgMail.setApiKey(SENDGRID_API_KEY);

exports.requestTurn = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const uid = context.auth.uid;
  console.log("UID: " + uid);
  const email = context.auth.token.email;
  console.log("Name: " + email);

  const send = "Here is your query number!";

  const docRef = db.collection("Users").doc(uid);
  const code = docRef.set({"sentEmail": send}, {merge: true});

  const msg = {
     to: email,
     from: "myemailaddress",
     templateId: TEMPLATE_ID,
     dynamic_template_data: {
        subject: "Welcome",
        CODE: send,
     }
  };

  const res = db.collection("mail").doc().set(msg);

  console.log("email saved to Firestore!");
  return sgMail.send(msg);
  // return {
  //   message: text,
  //   code,
  // };
})
```

**and this is how I call it from swiftui app:**

```
func requestTurn(){
        let data = ["Hello!"]
        
        functions.httpsCallable("requestTurn").call(data) { (result, error) in
            print("Function returned")
            if let err = error {print(err)}
            if let res = result {print(res)}
            
        }
```

and the mail that was supposed to be sent is saved with no problem in the mail collection.
[image: firestore database]

Comment: Do you see any error in the log? what if you catch the potential errors? In addition, note that you should chain the promises returned by the asynchronous `set()` and `send()` methods.

Comment: Hello, can I know how the return can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not very familiar with Sendgrid, however I have looked at documentation. I think this is related with the fact that according to the [documentation](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/tree/main/packages/mail) `send` is asynchronous method so, if you do not await for it, Cloud function will end before.
Actually I think that it might work, if you will add `then` as in example from the docs:

```
sgMail
  .send(msg)
  .then(() => {}, error => {
    console.error(error);
```

I am not sure if it will solve the case, however it should give you possible error massage.